# Html map and area shows 0 x 0

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to place a map over a picture to make it clickable. I have used https://www.image-map.net/ to find the map area coords, however, the area is not working. When I inspect the page with chrome developer tools it is shown as a 0x0 area. Here is the code.

```
<img
  className="SlideContainer"
  src={first_screen3}
  alt="firstimage"
  useMap="#image-map"
/>
<map name="image-map">
  <area
    target="_blank"
    alt="test"
    title="test"
    href="https://www.youtube.com"
    coords="628,979,651,963,660,934,647,904,628,891,204,891,181,904,168,927,171,953,184,973,207,983"
    shape="poly"
  />
</map>
```

[image: page image with chrome developer tools]

[image: Click me to see the image]
The section that I want to be clickable is where it says "view Menu".

Thanks!

Comment: Add a code snippet that points out your issue.

Comment: can i add the zip file of the react app?